# VMware installation error on Dell PE R715

Tags: vmware-esxi, dell-poweredge, dell-perc, h700

We have just purchased 2 x Dell Power Edge R715 with the PERC H700 raid contoller, each machine has 6 x 300GB SAS drives.

I have set 2 drives up in raid 0 and 4 drives in raid 10 on each machine, but when installing ESX4 I cannot see any target disks for the installation.

This is my first time installing ESX4, am I missing something?  Do I need a raid driver for ESX4?  The documentation I have says that the H700 is supported.

Comment: Please clarify whether you're installing ESX or ESXi; your text and your tags do not match.

Comment: wouldn't recommend RAID 0 for a server...RAID 1 sure.

Comment: I am going to go a step further than @august and say that if you put RAID0 on a server, especially a production server, you're committing gross negligence, and you can expect the sky to fall on your head the second a HDD gets a read error.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the Dell specific .iso? If I remember correctly those are required for the Dell hardware. <del>I'm currently stuck on my iPhone with edge, so I can't easily get a link at the moment :)</del>

The OEM cd images should be on the VMware.com site under the OEM tab: http://downloads.vmware.com/d/info/datacenter_downloads/vmware_vsphere_hypervisor_esxi/4_0#drivers_tools

Comment: This will fix your issue, most likely.